# How can you map/"resink" the input side of a StreamController

Tags: dart

Say I have a `StreamController<int>` called `myController`. I understand that I can map the **output** of the stream by doing something like `Stream<int> intStream = myController.map((i) => i * 2)` and then listen to that.

But what if I wanted to intercept/map the **input** of the sink, how would I achieve this? Is there an API for this? For clarity, have a look at this fake non-working example: `Sink<bool> boolSink = myController.sink.resink<int>((bool b) => b ? 1 : 0)`. So a mapping that takes a sink of bools and converts it to a sink of ints. Then I would do `boolSink.add(true)` and expect `intStream` to emit `1`.

My goal is to provide simplified sinks (`Sink<void>`) to a few components, but without them having to place the particular value into the sink (because they will each only ever be adding a predefined value). And ideally without having to manage multiple `StreamControllers` myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to have a class which implements the `Sink` interface. It intercepts calls to the `add` method, maps the value being added to a new value, and then forwards it on to the "real" sink. I need a new instance of the class for each type of mapping.

```dart
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

typedef Mapper<T, R> = R Function(T);

/// A [Sink] which takes a value of type [T] and maps it to a destination sink
/// which expects a value of type [R].
class SinkMapper<T, R> implements Sink<T> {
  final Mapper<T, R> _mapper;
  final Sink<R> _sink;

  SinkMapper({
    @required Mapper<T, R> mapper,
    @required Sink<R> sink,
  })  : _mapper = mapper,
        _sink = sink;

  @override
  void add(T data) => _sink.add(_mapper(data));

  @override
  void close() => _sink.close();
}
```